# Python2 and Python3 compatibility

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-c-api

I am reading the filename and run the `PyRun_SimpleFile` function. 
Below logic is not recommended because if there is compiler mismatch then below code may crash in windows.

Not recommended :-

```c
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (!fp)
    return;
if (PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, filename) != 0)
    return;
```

So above logic, I have implemented in Python 2 (As per below) which is working fine. 
How to implemend in python 3 (# else part in below code) because PyFile_FromString and PyFile_AsFile is not supported in Python 3.

```c
#ifdef PYTHON2
    PyObject* PyFileObject = PyFile_FromString(filename, (char *)"r");
    if (PyRun_SimpleFile(PyFile_AsFile(PyFileObject), filename) != 0)
        return;
#else
    //How to implement in Python3 above logic.. As PyFile_FromString and   
    //PyFile_AsFile is not supported in Python 3.
#endif
```

Can anyone suggest how to implement in Python 3?

Comment: How big is the file? Can you read the file into a string and use PyRun_SimpleString?

Comment: That i will implement if there will no solution for python 3 for above API.

Comment: In *Objects/fileobject.c* is a function `open_the_file()` which is called in `PyFile_FromString()`. Maybe you should replicate this in your program instead.

Comment: Successful use of the PyRun*File* routines requires that the Python interpreter and the current C runtime and the particular OS/Filesystem all use the same stdio conventions. This is not guaranteed, particularly on non-Unix based systems.